# ¿Por qué Phpmailer me sirve en un servidor web de Ubuntu, y a la hora que lo paso a otro no me sirve?

Tags: phpmailer

cabe mencionar que en los dos códigos es lo mismo, solo lo que varia es el cambio de servidor, y me sirve en uno y en otro no, el servidor de correos que utilizo es officce 365

Gracias

Comment: configuraciones diferentes

Comment: ¿No sirve? ¿Y qué es lo que indica que no sirve? ¿Qué mensaje de error o qué fallo da? ¿Está la librería instalada en ese otro servidor?

Comment: A que te refieres con instalar Phpmailer en el server ?

Comment: Gracias, a que te refieres con instalar phpmailer en el server,  es que  el problema es que no me envia ningun error el cod eseste, en un servidor me sirve pero a la hora que lo paso al otro no:

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un archivo php, el cual implemento con PHPMAILER, en un servidor web con Ubuntun  corre, pero a la hora de pasarlo al otro (exactamente igual) no, y no me manda ningún error

Answer (score -1):

este seria el cod a nivel general:

try {

```
  $correoRemitente = trim("correoEmpresa");
  $contrasena      = trim("contraseña");
  $nombre          = trim("Logistica ");
  $mail  = new PHPMailer();

  $mail->IsSMTP();

  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
  $mail->Host = "outlook.office365.com";
  $mail->Port = 25;

  $mail->Username = $correoRemitente;
  $mail->Password = $contrasena;

  $mail->From     = $correoRemitente;
  $mail->FromName = "Logistica CONICO";

  $mail->Subject = "Encomienda";
  $mail->addAddress("p@gmail.com", $nombreCliente);
  $mail->addAddress($correoVend, "Ventas");
  $mail->addAddress("p@gmail.com", "Confirmación de correo");


  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $body = '<html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            </head>
            <body style="font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif">
              <h3>Estimado: '.$nombreCliente.'</h3>
              <p>prueba de software conico </p>
              <br>
              <img height="15%" width="60%" src="../imagenes/FIRMA.png">
            </body>
            </html>';
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);

  if($mail->Send()){
    $msg= "En hora buena el mensaje ha sido enviado con exito a '.$destino.'";
  }
  else{
    $msg = "Lo siento, ha habido un error al enviar el mensaje a $destino";
  }


  } catch (Exception $e){

    echo 'Excepción capturada: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";

  }
```

pero como menciono en un server me sirve pero en otro no

Comment: deberias editar tu pregunta y pegar este codigo , no podes responder tu pregunta con tu codigo